# What to expect when entering Schengen area on a C type tourist visa? Will border agents question me? Will I have to present more than my passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, airports, schengen-visas, officials

I'm excited that my Schengen C type tourist visa got approved and I will be able to visit the Schengen area as a tourist soon. Specifically, I will arrive in Germany by plane.

I had to submit so many documents to the embassy for the visa application and following the proper guidelines. So now I'm anxious about making a mistake at the border. All I have is the visa sticker in my passport. Do I need to bring anything else? Will border agents ask questions? What procedures should I expect?

Unfortunately I don't know anyone who could speak from personal experience as a non-EU citizen. But I have heard from friends traveling back home (on an EU passport) that the non-EU citizen queue at the airport border control is usually a mess and it takes a long time to get processed and they get asked a lot.

Comment: Are you planning to follow the itinerary you presented in your visa application?  If there have been any changes, you should be prepared to justify them so the passport inspector doesn't conclude that your visa application was deceptive.  Such changes are allowed to a certain degree, but if you applied saying you want to go to a certain museum in Berlin and you arrive with plans to spend the entire visit at a conference in Munich, you will have more trouble than you would if you simply changed your accommodation to a different hotel.

Comment: @phoog I didn't have to fill out a full itinerary for the visa application. Only the hotel booking confirmation for the first stay. Will the border agent have all this information available to them?

Comment: You should assume that they do.  I don't think you have much to worry about, though, unless you've made some drastic change that you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You *will* be asked for the purpose of your visit. Beyond that the questions will be as deemed needed by the border control officer talking to you.

You *may* be asked all the same questions you've already answered in your visa application and interview, and you *may* be asked to prove your ability to provide for yourself for the duration of your visit and your intention to leave at the end of it (including explaining where you'll be staying, how you'll be paying for it, and when and how you'll be leaving).

Whether or not you'll be asked for any of that depends on a variety of factors, some determined at the initial encounter with the border agent. For example, if you look stressed or concerned (or alternatively, too chill and relaxed for a first time traveler) and give a vibe to the interviewer that you may not be truthful - expect more questions.

Remember, having a visa doesn't guarantee you the right to entry, it only guarantees you the right to approach.

Comment: They do not usually turn people with a valid visa back, unless the visitor does stupid things like saying that he wants to overstay. Basically two questions: Are you the person who is listed in the visa? They might ask for your name and birthdate when they have your passport in hand and you do not. And seeing you at the border, does it seem that your application was truthful? They might ask what you want to do in Europe, and check if the answers match with your appearance.

Comment: @om `They do not usually turn people with a valid visa back, unless the visitor does stupid things like saying that he wants to overstay.` - not necessarily *saying*, but not being able to answer "where are you staying" and "how are you paying for that" would most definitely put the visitor on the next flight back. And I have been asked that myself, numerously in multiple different countries, so yes, they do ask.

Comment: Yes, the visitor should be prepared for check questions like that.

Comment: "You _will_ be asked for the purpose of your visit": that was never my experience entering as an Annex II (visa-exempt) traveler, though it's been many years since I've done that.  Have things changed, or are travelers with visas more likely to be asked?  (Also, as a technical nitpick, a Schengen visa is more than right to approach; it is also authorization to remain, which is why it must be valid throughout the stay, but that doesn't change the fact that having one is no guarantee of entry.)

Comment: @littleadv "You will be asked for the purpose of your visit. Beyond that the questions will be as deemed needed by the border control officer talking to you." So the purpose of my visit is that I want to visit family and friends, so what other questions can I expect? Will I have to provide proof like family pictures or something? I didn't have to provide an "invitation letter" for the visa application.

Comment: @littleadv "you may be asked to prove your ability to provide for yourself for the duration of your visit" How much money do they expect me to bring at minimum? I guess a good way would be to bring cash? I only found minimums for "student visas" which was around 1000 € per month. So if I bring 1000/30 € per day I should be good?

Comment: @littleadv "and your intention to leave at the end of it" For example by providing my paid plane ticket confirmation for the return flight as well as my work contract and vacation request from my home country?

Comment: @o.m. "They might ask what you want to do in Europe, and check if the answers match with your appearance" What do you mean when you say appearance? What should my appearance be if I want to visit friends and family and do some sight seeing with them?

Comment: @CannedMeatLover you missed the point of my answer. You *may* be asked for all of these things, none of them, or anywhere in between. We cannot know ahead of time what will be asked of *you* specifically.

Comment: @littleadv I'm sorry if you feel like I didn't appreciate your answer enough. It was very helpful. I just have lots of follow-up questions. You see, I don't think I'm very special. So I also expect my experience at the border to not be vastly different than everyone else's. That's why it's very helpful to hear some experiences from others. For example, I am aware that just because someone else was allowed to enter with 500 € for two weeks, doesn't guarantee that it will be good for me, too. But it's a rough estimate what to expect.

Comment: @CannedMeatLover, the immigration officer will do a quick check if the passport and visa are yours, and if your entry appears plausible. Not many questions, **usually**, because they don't have much time. But they take a little more time when things do not seem normal. A business traveler with a surfboard is not normal. A tourist in a tuxedo is not normal, unless the purpose is to go to the opera (or to a wedding). If things are unexpected, they ask and listen to the answer. You should **be able** to answer questions like "where are you staying" and "how are you leaving" like a normal tourist.

Comment: @CannedMeatLover, (continued), that means the answer to "where are you staying" might well be "I have the details somewhere in my backpack." That is normal for a tourist.

Comment: @o.m. Thank you. I'm still not sure if I'm overlooking something, but so far my experience with officials was that they usually expect very specific answers to their questions. So regarding "how are you leaving" an answer "I'm going to walk back home" might be 100% truthful, but I think the border agent won't like the answer. Therefore, I'm questioning if my booking confirmation for the return flight is even enough. (I am not actually going to walk of course haha.) I am just afraid I'll mess it up by putting my foot in my mouth at the last possible moment.

Comment: Furthermore regarding "where are you staying" I have read that some visa applications require the applicant to submit a full travel itinerary. I didn't have to and I still don't really know what exactly I'll do every single day. Is that a red flag for the official? Should I work out a full itinerary in advance?

Comment: @CannedMeatLover you're coming to visit friends/family. You have (supposedly) their phone numbers and addresses readily available to be verified. You have your return flight booked. You have some credit cards and cash that would be enough for you to enjoy your travel (how much is enough? Don't know - 100EUR/day?). You can show all that if asked. Sit back, relax, and enjoy your flight.

Comment: @CannedMeatLover "Is that a red flag for the official? Should I work out a full itinerary in advance?": No.  Immigration officers are looking for inconsistencies.  There's no need to create detail that wasn't on your visa application.  Not having everything completely planned is perfectly reasonable, especially if you're visiting friends or family.

Comment: They asked me how long I would be staying and for what purpose. I said I might stay forever and didn't know. They said, "umm..." and I added, but I know about Schengen so I won't stay longer than is legal. And they said "good thing you know about schengen" *stamp* "Next".

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer regarding the question if passport/visa is enough: No.

See European Commission, Migration and Home Affairs https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2020-08/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf

> 16 Do I have to present any other document at the Schengen external
> borders apart from my travel document with the Schengen visa?
>
> The short-stay visa does not automatically entitle you to enter the Schengen area. At
> border (or during other controls) you may have to show the visa but also provide
> additional documentation, for example information on that you have sufficient means
> to cover the stay and the return trip. It is therefore recommended that you carry with
> you copies of the documents, which you presented when applying for the visa (e.g.
> letters of invitation, travel confirmations, other documents stating the purpose of your
> stay).